# java AWT FileDialog modify the files of type list

Tags: java, awt, filedialog

I've been searching a lot for this issue, but couldn't find a solution for it. I'm using a FileDialog in my java program and I want to change the 'File Type' list, or the file extensions accepted..

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv5n2.png)

I know this is doable with a JFileChooser, but I don't like how swing components look (buttons, menus and so on..)

So, is there a way to do this with the FileDialog?

edit:

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.MenuBar;
import java.awt.MenuItem;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Start {

    private static final String MODEL_EXTENSION = ".modl";

    private static final int w = 650, h = 600;

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static MenuBar jmb;
    public static Canvas canvas;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        frame = new JFrame("Model Editor");
        frame.setSize(w,h);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        jmb = new MenuBar();
        frame.setMenuBar(jmb);

        Button b = new Button();
        frame.add(b);

        initFileMenu();
        initEditMenu();
    }

    private static void initFileMenu() {

        Menu file = new Menu("File");
        jmb.add(file);

        MenuItem file_new = new MenuItem("New");
        file.add(file_new);

        MenuItem file_open = new MenuItem("Open File...");
        file.add(file_open);
        file_open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame);
                fd.setFile("*" + MODEL_EXTENSION);

                fd.setFilenameFilter(new ExtensionFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(MODEL_EXTENSION, "Model in MODL format")));

                fd.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        file.addSeparator();

        MenuItem file_close = new MenuItem("Close");
        file.add(file_close);
        file_close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            }
        });
    }

    private static void initEditMenu() {

        Menu edit = new Menu("Edit");
        jmb.add(edit);

        MenuItem undo = new MenuItem("Undo");
        edit.add(undo);

        MenuItem redo = new MenuItem("Redo");
        edit.add(redo);

        edit.addSeparator();
    }

}

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public final class ExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private final FileNameExtensionFilter extFilter;

    public ExtensionFilter() {
        this(new FileNameExtensionFilter("MODL file", "modl"));
    }

    public ExtensionFilter(FileNameExtensionFilter extFilter) {
        this.extFilter = extFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return extFilter.accept(new File(dir, name));
    } 
}
```

Comment: The very example in the [JFileChooser javadoc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) gives you the hint.

Comment: If 'FileNameExtensionFilter' is what you mean, you can't add a FileNameExtensionFilter to a FileDialog...

Comment: You know you can change how Swing components look, right?  Every Swing program I’ve written starts with `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`.

Comment: @Janez Kuhar The method setFilenameFilter(FilenameFilter) in the type FileDialog is not applicable for the arguments (FileNameExtensionFilter)

Comment: @Reketar I'm sorry, my mistake.